Retrive actual file name from Rails ActiveStorage S3 file name
I have to migrate assets(images) from Rails ActiveStorage uploaded file to S3 into my another WordPress website.
However, it seems the filename is they Blob key similar to as below:
5jEWBoezkaNyJtQA1icpnuSs
Is there any way to retrieve the actual file name like "docker-life-cycle" out of above key name?
Note: Someone mentioned a way in this question (see comment) Active Storage with Amazon S3 not saving with filename specified but using file key instead

Have you tried filename? It seems like the key and the filename are both stored during upload? You cannot turn the key into a filename if that is the question because the key is simply SecureRandom.base36(28)

If you have something like the following:
class Asset
  has_one_attached :image
end

Then you'd be able to access the filename of an assets image as follows:
asset = Asset.last
asset.image.filename # returns an ActiveStorage::Filename object
asset.image.filename.to_s # i.e. image.png etc

Bear in mind that if asset doesn't have an image set, then filename will return nil, and and filename.to_s will return "", so you'll want to handle that accordingly.
If you mean you only have the blob key and want to work from there to find the filename, it'd be something like this:
blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.find_by(key: 'my_key')
blob.filename # returns an ActiveStorage::Filename object
blob.filename.to_s # again, filename as a string, i.e. image.png

